# Odoo TypeError: 'NewId' object is not iterable

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to create an activity when a stage change occurs but keep getting `TypeError: 'NewId' object is not iterable` .
I figured out that `@onchange` creates a new object which replaces `self` and I am guessing this is the errors cause.

Here is my code:

```
class ProjectSetAndDateType(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task.type'

    last_stage = fields.Boolean(string="Fertigstellungsstufe")


class ProjectSetEndDate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    @api.onchange('stage_id')
    def _set_end_date(self):
        if self.stage_id.last_stage:
            self.kanban_state = "done"
            self.date_finished = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            activity_deadline = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)

            data = {
                'res_id':  self._origin.id,
                'res_model': 'project.task',
                'res_model_id': self.env['ir.model'].search([('model', '=', 'project.task')]).id,
                'user_id': self._origin.project_id.user_id.id,
                'summary': 'Aufgabe archivieren nach Fertigstellung',
                'activity_type_id': self.env.ref('project_set_end_date.mail_set_end_date_archive').id,
                'date_deadline': activity_deadline
                }
            self.env['mail.activity'].create(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'NewId' object is an recordset, when you are creating any new record odoo will store it in newid class , not in database and you are trying to write the kanban_state, date_finished in the record which is not yet created.
I suggest you to change the logic and rewrite this code on the write or create method,

**Note: make sure you don't create any record on onchange method because it is very risky and not user friendly.**

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right track. I rewrote it in write and had to tweak the conditions but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote it to this, now it is working as expected.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime


class ProjectSetAndDateType(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task.type'

    last_stage = fields.Boolean(string="Fertigstellungsstufe")


class ProjectSetEndDate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        if 'stage_id' in vals:
            final_stage = self.env['project.task.type'].search([('id', '=', vals['stage_id'])]).last_stage
            if final_stage:
                vals['kanban_state'] = "done"
                vals['date_finished'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                activity_deadline = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=40)

                data = {
                    'res_id':  self.id,
                    'res_model': 'project.task',
                    'res_model_id': self.env['ir.model'].search([('model', '=', 'project.task')]).id,
                    'user_id': self.project_id.user_id.id,
                    'summary': 'Aufgabe archivieren nach Fertigstellung',
                    'activity_type_id': self.env.ref('project_set_end_date.mail_set_end_date_archive').id,
                    'date_deadline': activity_deadline
                    }
                self.env['mail.activity'].create(data)

        res = super().write(vals)
        return res
```